# HTML call to TypeScript function not executing

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to click a button on an HTML page and have it call a TypeScript function. But the function, `getToken()`, never gets called. I've tested the function by calling it from the constructor and the function works just fine. No errors or warnings appear in the browser's Console.

app.module.ts (contains the `getToken` method I want to call from HTML)

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})


@Injectable()
export class AppModule {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    private _token: string;

    public getToken() {
        let url = "https://my.domain.net/oauth/token";

        let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        urlSearchParams.append('grant_type', 'password');
        urlSearchParams.append('username', 'myUserName');
        urlSearchParams.append('password', 'myPassword');
        let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

        this.http.post(url, body)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
            data => { this._token = data.access_token; alert("TOKEN: " + this._token); console.log(data); },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('Fetching complete for Server Metrics')
        );
    }
}
```

How the TypeScript's function is being called in the HTML file:

```
<button (click)="getToken()">Get Token</button>
```

Comment: `getToken() {...}` needs to be a method of the component `<button (click)="getToken()" ...>` has in its template. Your `getToken()` is in `AppModule` which doesn't make any sense at all. Please check the tutorials at https://angular.io

Comment: A downvote for an ostensibly innocent question?.angular.io is focused on version 4; I have to work with version 2.

Comment: There isn't much difference between 2 and 4 (I didn't downvote)

Comment: Thank you, Günter, I'm now working through the angular.io Heroes tutorial. With Pierre's answer below, I was able to get the click event to work and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

Well... there are some fundamental issues with your code. At first I would suggest you take a look at the guides written on https://angular.io.

- You are making your `AppModule` an `@Injectable`. This is wrong..
- You got logic inside your `AppModule`
- You are under the assumption you can execute a method in a class from any template. You can only do that from a template inside the `template` of a component, or inside the `templateUrl`.

To make it work for you, you should remove the `@Injectable()`, and move your logic to your `AppComponent`. Given that there are no other errors

Comment: Pierre, thank you very much for your guidance. I did everything you listed and now it's working.